# Java PreparedStatement syntax issues

Tags: java, sql, derby

I'm having some issues with SQL syntax errors when using Java PreparedStatements.

The three statements I'm trying to prepare are as follows:

```
insertBook = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Books ? VALUES ?");
selectBooks = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Books?");
deleteBooks = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Books?");
```

In the first statement, I'd like to pass in two strings, one containing a list of columns to insert into, and the other containing all the values to insert. In the other two statements, I'd like to insert an (optional) WHERE clause at the end.

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739408/why-am-i-getting-a-syntax-error-with-this-prepared-statement) question which appears to deal with a similar issue, but in his case it appeared that he was trying to use the ?s where it didn't make sense; unless I've failed at SQL, I can't see any reason why I shouldn't be able to insert my strings here. I've scoured the Javadocs, but can't seem to come up with an explanation there, either.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can't use `prepareStatement()` that way. Why don't you concatenate the Strings and then pass the result into the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how it was designed. ?-s left for only parameters, Consider to use `StringBuilder` to concatenate your 'WHERE' clauses.

This is just a simple case u may not use `StringBuilder` here, it is effective for building complex queries

Here is your example

```
String whereClause = " WHERE Id = ?";

String insert = "INSERT INTO [Table](C1, C2) VALUES(?, ?)";
String select = "SELECT * FROM [Table] ";
String update = "UPDATE [Table] SET C1 = ? ";
String delete = "DELETE FROM [Table] ";

PreparedStatement insertSt = con.prepareStatement(insert);
PreparedStatement selectSt = con.prepareStatement(select + whereClause);
PreparedStatement deleteSt = con.prepareStatement(update + whereClause);
PreparedStatement updateSt = con.prepareStatement(delete + whereClause);
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` looks very promising. Is there simply no way to use a `PreparedStatement` in this situation then? I'm relatively new to JavaDB.

Comment: @lan Knight StringBuilder is only for concatenation of strings, You still need to use PreparedStatement to execute queries

Answer (score 0):

For your first statement:

```
insertBook = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Books ? VALUES ?");
```

I will start with the second `?`, after `VALUES`.  Since you have only one `?` you have only one placeholder and so can pass only one value to the statement.  That part, alone, makes your goal unattainable with JDBC.  In fact, the prepareStatement() will, for some drivers and databases at least, send the statement to the database server instructing it to prepare the statement.  The server will, at that time, parse and plan the statement and so the columns and number of parameters must be known at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The "?" in JDBC ties closely to the parameter replacement supported by the underlying DBMS protocol. However, you're attempting to change the actual SQL that is being sent to the DB, not replacing parameters.